# Properties option missing from a GPO setting

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Computer Configuration/Window Settings/Security Settings/Public Key Policies/Trusted Root Certification Authorities

In the settings tab of this GPO i can see there is a setting defined under properties of this setting. When i google this setting they are also talking about properties of this setting. But its missing. There is no "Properties" when i right click the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder.

Tried accessing this GPO from 4 different servers, all are Windows Server 2008 R2. Anyone have any tips on how i can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Although the GPMC Settings tab shows these properties as being under the Trusted Root Certification Authorities section, to set them in 2008R2 use the Certificate Path Validation Settings entry under the Public Key Policies parent folder.  Under 2003 there was a Properties context menu option, but it looks like MS altered this at 2008 or 2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was researching the same thing. Most of the time I expect only the configured settings to show up in a group policy report showing the settings of that GPO. This stumped me until I figured out that the settings of this particular policy show in the report output even though they were not configured.

As Mike_P states, these settings are available in the "Certificate Path Validation Settings" item. This policy setting is found at Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Public Key Policies

On its "Trusted Publishers" tab, checking "Define these policy settings", then selecting "Allow all administrators and users to manage user's own Trusted Publishers" and "Verify that the publisher certificate is not revoked" will yield the same results in the report as it does when this item is not configured.

Comment: By-the-way, this does not seem to be the case in new GPOs. It seems to be unique to the Default Domain Policy. I've verified that making the settings I mentioned in my first post results in the same settings that appear in the Default Domain Policy report.